# LUKS encrypted swap partition is no longer recognized after power failure

Tags: mount, partition, swap, luks

I have a linux mint 18 installation with a luks encrypted / and swap partitions.    `/` which is `/dev/sda6` unlocks and mounts fine at boot up. The system then goes into emergency mode.   journalctl says timeout trying to reach the swap partition.

I tried running `cryptsetup open --type luks /dev/sda5 sda5_crypt`and that returns
`Device /dev/sda5 is not a valid LUKS device.`

Comment: If the swap partition got zotted by a dirty shutdown, you might just have to destroy the swap partition entirely - including the encrypted container - and recreate it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

DopeGhoti is correct.

To confirm a corrupted LUKS header, you can use the following command:

```
cryptsetup luksDump /dev/sda5
```

You should get the same error message.

To fix it, re-create the LUKS container, setup the swap again, *and* take a backup of the LUKS header. Something like this:

```
cryptsetup luksFormat /dev/sda5
cryptsetup open --type luks /dev/sda5 sda5_crypt
mkswap -L SWAP /dev/mapper/sda5_crypt
swapon -L SWAP
cryptsetup luksHeaderBackup /dev/sda5 --header-backup-file /root/sda5_luks_header.img
```

The LUKS header is so vulnerable. There's only one copy so when you lose it, there's no way to unlock the device. Unless... you have a backup ;)